# Cannot install mysql

Tags: software-installation, mysql, php

When I execute `sudo apt-get install mysql php7` in my vmware, it goes well in the beginning, but in the end, it shows:

```
Unable to locate mysql php7
```

why would this situation happen?

Is it because I choose to get `mysql` and `php` service when I installed the system? Whether my system get the service or not?

在虚拟机中执行sudo apt-get install mysql php7时前面都是Done，最后一条是Unable to locate mysql 和php7 ，这是为什么呢？是因为我在安装的时候选择装了他们吗？那到底我的虚拟机里有没有mysql和php服务？
  有人能帮帮我吗？

Answer (score 0):

If the issue is not network related, try the following:

```
sudo apt-get install mysql-server php7.0
```

Sometimes it can be how the packages are named. if encountered again, use this command to search your configured repositories:

```
sudo apt search php7
```

Or name of the package you wish to find.

Hope this helps.